# Python Permutations Limited to only increasing numbers

Tags: python, permutation

I'm trying to create a function that will produce all permutations of a list but limited to only sets of `len(n)` and only increasing from left to right. For instance, if I have list `l = [2,4,6,8,10]` and `n = 3`, the results should be

```
[2,4,6],
[2,4,8],
[2,4,10],
[2,6,8],
[2,6,10],
[2,8,10],
[4,6,8],
[4,6,10],
[6,8,10]
```

I've seen plenty of variations of permutation functions but none with this kind of restriction.

Comment: Combinations by nature are not repeated so if you have a sorted list, `list(itertools.combinations(l, 3))`  should work just fine?

Comment: @ayhan that should be the answer. Or maybe `[list(x) for x in itertools.combinations(lst, 3)]` to create sublists, not tuples.

Comment: @ayhan are we sure order is guaranteed not to change?

Comment: @AAron you mean order of the sublists? you can always sort your result if you're not sure

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre true, but it'd be nice to not have to do that extra step if we know we don't have to

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I thought maybe it can be treated as a duplicate but I've added the details about sorting.

Comment: @ayhan I don't blame you for answering a duplicate, because the sorting part is new, that's true. Closing as a duplicate now that you answered was the right thing to do: your answer answers this very question, and the duplicate probably offers more variety.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [itertools docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

> Combinations are emitted in lexicographic sort order. So, if the input iterable is sorted, the combination tuples will be produced in sorted order.

So if you have a sorted list, then using [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) you'll get your desired result. If not, you can call `sorted()`  first.

```
lst = range(2, 11, 2)

list(itertools.combinations(lst, 3))
Out: 
[(2, 4, 6),
 (2, 4, 8),
 (2, 4, 10),
 (2, 6, 8),
 (2, 6, 10),
 (2, 8, 10),
 (4, 6, 8),
 (4, 6, 10),
 (4, 8, 10),
 (6, 8, 10)]
```